# Use Alternate Extension for .sql files in Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm looking for a way to have sql server treat a different file extension as an .sql file... My company policy is that we name stored procedures as .PRC instead of .SQL. This makes it a hassle to open a file and edit/execute it. While I can associate SQL Server Management Studio to open the file, it doesn't treat it as a script so all the options to execute the script as well as color coding of the script are disabled.

Currently I have to copy out the script and paste it into a new query, then when I'm done editing paste it back and save it. This is all related to our source control and is a major pain. Any way to fool sql server and have it treat these as .sql files so I can execute them directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the extension from the options dialog (tools->options). Then under Text Editor-File Extension and then choose the editing experience you want

[image]

Once applied you can use it as you did .SQL. In the following image note the highlighting and the result set on the file SQLQuery.rpc

[image]

Comment: @ConradFrix- once it is applied. dod you try to open new tab and new tab has extension .rpc. Sorry I could not understand.

Comment: @RGI yep that's what the second image was about. Note the highlighting and the result set. I updated my answer to clarify